# How do I remove this peephole viewer?

Tags: doors

How do I remove this peephole viewer?

[image]

I haven't been able to find one like this on YouTube how-to videos so I'm guessing it's an older style.

On the outside of the door is a gold plate surrounding the viewer, I can provide a photo if necessary.

The door is metal, about an inch thick.

Comment: Is the intention to make it so that no light gets through in either direction? If so, some aluminium foil folded over three or four times and taped over the lens will accomplish that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part near the lens is threaded, so you should be able to unscrew the front from the back by turning that circular plate with the notches. The notches are certainly meant for tightening and loosening.